# Defining new math symbols and specify how they behave under commands such as \mathrm

Tags: macros, symbols, unicode-math, font-encodings, math-fonts

I want to define a math symbol `\dbar` which will display its italic version normally, but display upright when it appears inside `\mathrm`.

My naïve attempt is something like this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stix2}

\DeclareSymbolFont{stix2-italic}{T1}{stix2}{m}{it}
\DeclareSymbolFont{stix2-upright}{T1}{stix2}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\dbar}{\mathalpha}{stix2-italic}{158}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\updbar}{\mathalpha}{stix2-upright}{158}

\begin{document}
$\dbar \mathrm{\dbar} \updbar$
\end{document}
```

which outputs:

[image]

This is expected since the [`stix2`](https://ctan.org/pkg/stix2-type1?lang=en) package uses `LS1` encoding for `\mathrm`, which has `⪯` at position 158, while `T1` encoding has `đ` at that position.

Is there a way to define the command `\dbar` so that it will display as

`\DeclareMathSymbol{\dbar}{\mathalpha}{stix2-italic}{158}`

normally but display as

`\DeclareMathSymbol{\updbar}{\mathalpha}{stix2-upright}{158}`

when it appears inside the scope of `\mathrm`? I do not want to modify the behavior of the [`stix2`](https://ctan.org/pkg/stix2-type1?lang=en) package or of how any other glyph interacts with `\mathrm`. I would also be interested in hearing solutions involving the [`unicode-math`](https://ctan.org/pkg/unicode-math) package.

Answer (score 1):

There are two different things `\mathrm` can mean: upright math symbols (such as constants in ISO style) and short lines of text in math mode.

Both Unicode and the T1 encoding have the đ (U+0111) character, as itself or `\dj`, so you could set `\mathrm` to either encoding and use `\mathrm{\dj}`.

However, you are more likely to want to define this command with `\text` from `amsmath` or `amstext`, or similar.  A pair of commands for upright and italic math symbols might be:

```
\newcommand\dstrokeup{\textup{\dj}}
\newcommand\dstrokeit{\textit{\dj}}
```

If you really do want a command that changes its shape depending on whether you’re in math or text mode, that could be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{iftex}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\iftutex
  \usepackage{fontspec}
\else
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\fi

\newcommand\dstroke{%
  \ifmmode{\textit{\dj}}%
  \else{\dj}%
  \fi}

\begin{document}
\( \dstroke \text{ is {\dstroke} in text mode.}\)
\end{document}
```